# Does startActivityForResult starting a new Activity notify the calling Activity when the started Activity finishes?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I was looking at an Android question there asking if the following statement was true..

When `startActivityForResult` is used to launch a new `Activity` from your `Activity` class then your `Activity` class gets notified when the new `Activity` is completed.

I was under the opinion, the whole point of `startActivityForResult` was to notify the calling Activity that the Activity it started has completed and allow data to be returned if wanted.

I am relatively new to Android and I want to get my facts straight.

Any input would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When startActivityForResult is used to launch a new activity from your
>   activity class then your activity class gets notified when the new
>   activity is completed.

this is true, `onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` is called in activity, which started other activity for result - override it to handle result

> I was under the opinion, the whole point of startActivityForResult was
>   to notify the calling Activity that the Activity it started has
>   completed and allow data to be returned if wanted.

thats also true, you can set result in activity called for result by calling `setResult (int resultCode, Intent data)` - passing Intent data containing extra data - then you can retreive it from Intent data in onActivityResult.

Comment: Cheers, appreciate the confirmation!

Answer (score 1):

For sanity sake, let's have `Activity A` and `Activity B`!

`ActivityA` starts `ActivityB` with `startActivityForResult`.

`ActivityB` does it's thing and completes. `onActivityResult` is called on `ActivityA`

Answer (score 0):

You use startActivityForResult when you want that the called activity returns a result to the calling activity.
The calling activity has to implement onActivityResult to get notified about the result.
When the called activity finish its work it calls setResult.
It is just a way to share values between activities and it has nothing to do with a notifying system.
I hope i was clear.

Comment: So you don't believe the initial statement is true as `onActivityResult` is an **optional** method that needs to be implemented for any sort of 'notification' to occur?

Comment: I think the fact you only ever use it is because you want to be notified means this is a true statement